# Onclick on different DIV tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]

I have two DIV tags. 
1) Green Color is outer Div Tag which has onclick property set to alert('Clicked').
2) Yellow Color is Inner DIV Tag

Now, when I perform a click on inner div tag an alert pops up. Same repeats while selecting items from inner div tag. I'm not able to select in the inner div tags. How can this be resolved?

Further more, I will have nested div tags which are generated dynamically. I'm stuck here

Comment: Posting your code would make it easier for us to understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the propagation of your click up to the outer div.

Sorry about the repost, but the answer is already located at:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: The link you provided is relevant, but I don't think this fully answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set an event listener on your `outer` container, and, when the listener is triggered, only act after you have verified that the click did not originate from any of the container's children (in this case, `inner`). You could tweak this solution to only exclude specific children by class, id, etc:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var outer = $('.outer');
        outer.on('click', handleOuterClick);

    function handleOuterClick(e) {        
        //Assert that the click originated from the outer div, and not from
        //any of its children
        var origin = e.target,
            children = outer.children();
        if(children.index($(origin)) == -1) {
            //Proceed by displaying an alert
            alert("You clicked the outer div!");
        }

    };

});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39ssk/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. You can apply id, and use those ids to control onclick.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function manualToggle(val)
{
    alert(val.id);
}

</script>

<div id="test" onclick="manualToggle(this);">
    <span>Allowed to click</span>
    <span onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();">Not allowed to click</span>
    <span>Allowed to click</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```